# Function within another function does not execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recently been working on some JavaScript code along with jQuery to make a number pad. I am trying to allow keyboard input as well as on-page input by using an event listener for keydown.

The function **buttonOnclick(x)** will turn the x parameter into a number when it is called.

Event listener code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    return buttonOnclick(key);
});
```

`buttonOnclick` code:

```
var dec = 0;
var orderPrice = 0;

function buttonOnclick(x) {
    switch (x) {
    case 0:
        num = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        num = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        num = 2;
        break;
    case 3:
        num = 3;
        break;
    case 4:
        num = 4;
        break;
    case 5:
        num = 5;
        break;
    case 6:
        num = 6;
        break;
    case 7:
        num = 7;
        break;
    case 8:
        num = 8;
        break;
    case 9:
        num = 9;
        break;
    case 10:
        num = ".";
        break;
    case 11:
        num = "Backspace";
        break;
    case 12:
        num = "Enter";
        break;
    default:
        num = false;
    }
    if (num == false) {
        return;
    } else if (num < 10) {
        var value = $(".value").attr("value");
        var valLeng = value.length;
        if (valLeng < 7) {
            $(".value").attr("value", value + num);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Sorry if the code is difficult to understand, I always tidy up at the end.

Comment: As a sidenote, you shouldn't wait until the end to clean up your code. This code is already messy enough to not be maintainable anymore. That makes debugging extremely tedious. It's impossible to understand what is going on there. Please do yourself a favor and refactor your code already while you're coding. Use small functions dedicated to a single functionality. Factor out common code. This is a mess.

Comment: @MillerKoijam Within the event listener function, the buttonOnclick(x) code is not being executed. If I add alerts in there to alert(key) then it works but the function is not being executed. That's the issue

Comment: Either there is some error in your js or js is not enclosed within the Document.Ready function().

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme I have gotten rid of the code which shouldn't be needed for this to work, hope that helps.

Comment: First of all, where does `num` come from? Are you leaking a global? Secondly, why have a switch over the numbers and then only set it to the same numbers? That's completely redundant. Furthermore, please don't debug with `alert`. Go to https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging and learn how to use this. I am sure once you step through your code line by line you fill find the mistake. Without having your code running on a page, it's hard to find out what's really going on.

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme Without the event listener, the code works fine. And the alerts were a good debug reference as it showed that the function did not run.

Comment: Just add a `+` before `x` like `switch (+x)`. Youre sending a `string` to your function and then checking if it matches with numbers. What's your problem? :P

Comment: @BatuZet Thank you! This worked, and it was one of the few comments that suggested fixes instead of criticism! Thanks!